# Matplotlib - How to make line plots jump directly to data point

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a set of data that I am using to make a line plot on matplotlib. Is it possible to make the data directly jump to the data points, instead of having a positive/negative slope?

Below is an example of the plot.

[image]

Blue is what is automatically generated with the set of data, and red is what I want it to look like. I plotted this manually with a for loop and with `plt.plot` with just two coordinates. Is there a quicker way that doesn't involve manually doing it, and a built-in function for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`step`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.step.html) plot with the `where='post'` option:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [3, 8, 1, 10]

plt.plot(x, y, label='plot')
plt.step(x, y, where='post', label='step')
plt.legend()
```

[image]